# Set-WBPolicy: The Parameter is incorrect

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-server-backup

When configuring a backup using Powershell in Windows 2016 Core, I am receiving an unintelligible exception.

I have created a backup policy as follows:

```
$policy = New-WBPolicy

Add-WBBareMetalRecovery -Policy $policy
Add-WBSystemState -Policy $policy
$volumes = Get-WBVolume -VolumePath "C:"
Add-WBVolume -Policy $policy -Volume $volumes

$creds = Get-Credential
$target = New-WBBackupTarget -NetworkPath "\\some\network\path" -Credential $creds
Add-WBBackupTarget -Policy $policy -Target $target

Set-WBSchedule -Policy $policy -Schedule 06:00
Set-WBPolicy -Policy $policy
```

If I print `$policy` to console, it reads:

```
Schedule              : {05/08/2018 06:00:00}
BackupTargets         : {\\some\network\path}
VolumesToBackup       : {Local disk (C:)}
FilesSpecsToBackup    :
FilesSpecsToBackup    :
ComponentsToBackup    :
BMR                   : True
SystemState           : True
OverwriteOldFormatVhd : True
VssBackupOptions      : VssCopyBackup
```

But, when I call `SetWBPolicy -Policy $policy` it returns:

```
Set-WBPolicy : The parameter is incorrect
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WBPolicy -Policy $policy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WBPolicy], Exception
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Windows.ServerBackup.Commands.SetWBPolicy
```

I have tried creating the policy using `wbadmin` but it fails with the equally vague statement `The parameter is incorrect`, which I guess is just a print-out of the same exception.

Comment: I wonder if it's seeing the spaces in the Volumes to Backup Parameter as separate volumes?

Comment: @Davidw When creating the policy, the volumes were identified only by the drive letter. The label shown above is just an expanded view.

I was completely stumped by this and didn't want to waste time on on it, so I have setup a backup script on the host hypervisor that suspends the VM and clones the virtual disk. I'll leave the question up in case someone can provide more information about this exception.

Comment: How did you create the policy?

Comment: @Davidw I've added the steps I used to create the policy. For the record, I can run a one-off backup fine using `Start-WBBackup -Policy $policy`.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like it's not an issue with the policy itself, then.

Comment: @Davidw hence my confusion. If I get a chance I might try removing & reinstalling the Server Backup feature; though `sfc` didn't find any problems.